# Compute multiple distinct averages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, average

I'm fairly new to rails, and am still getting used to putting together methods. I'm currently trying to create a method that averages distinct data from multiple columns. I'd like to do it all in one method so that I can display the information easily in an html table.

Currently I have this in my model:

```
def averagedonate
    scores.group(:donatedate).average('donateamount')
    scores.group(:donatedate).average('rating')
end
```

I'd like to be able to use them in a table like this:

```
<% @averagedonate.each do |donatedate, donateamount, rating| %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= donatedate %></td>
    <td><%= donateamount %></td>
    <td><%= rating %></td>
  </tr>
```

How do I change my averagedonate method to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested, but something to this effect should work

```
def averagedonate    
    scores.select("
        AVG(donateamount) as avg_donateamount,
        AVG(rating) as avg_rating,
        donatedate
    ")
    .group(:donatedate)
end
```

Then use it like this

```
<% @averagedonate.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= item.donatedate %></td>
    <td><%= item.avg_donateamount %></td>
    <td><%= item.avg_rating %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```